# Correctly declare Typescript type inside Observable map function

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this `fetch` function in an Angular service.  It all works fine, but the TypeScript is complaining that *"Property 'statuses' does not exist on type 'Object'."*

I guess I need to create an Interface for the data object but when I tried that, I wasn't sure where to declare it.  I also tried declaring `HttpResponse` but that expects an argument.  Any clues would be great!

```
export class Status {
  constructor(
    public workflowId: string,
    public spawnTime: number,
    public spawnValue: string,
    public workflowName: string
  ) {
  }
}

fetch(command, params?) {
return this.http.post(`http://localhost:4000/${command}`, params)
  .pipe(
    map((data): Status[] => {
      const statuses = [];
      for (const status of Object.keys(data.statuses)) {
        const newStatus = new Status(
          status,
          data.statuses[status]['spawn-time'],
          data.statuses[status]['spawn-value'],
          data.statuses[status]['workflow-name']
        );
        statuses.push(newStatus);
      }
      return statuses;
    })
  )
  .pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}
```

Comment: What's in your `Status` object (properties)? Also is the `data` returned typeof `Status[]`? Pretty sure it's a `Response` object.

Comment: I've added some more info to the post

Comment: Can you provide some sample output from your data? I created stackblitz trying to replicate it. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p2zfrw

Comment: `data['statuses'][status]['spawn-time']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the answer with help from the other posts.  I had to created an interface for `data` because the response from the http request is just a json object.  Sorry, it took me a while to realise what was going on.  Here's the entire working solution which throws no TS errors or warning:

```
export interface Data {
  statuses: object;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EpisodeApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  fetch(command, params?) {
    return this.http.post(`http://localhost:4000/${command}`, params)
      .pipe(
        map((data: Data) => {
          const statuses: Status[] = [];
          for (const status of Object.keys(data.statuses)) {
            const newStatus = new Status(
              status,
              data.statuses[status]['spawn-time'],
              data.statuses[status]['spawn-value'],
              data.statuses[status]['workflow-name']
            );
            statuses.push(newStatus);
          }
          return statuses;
        })
      )
      .pipe(
        catchError(EpisodeApiService.handleError)
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example that how to parse the information from json.
In this example you need to do a internal `map` **inside** of your **first** `map` it is going to work as  iterator  then you return you object parsed as interface `<Status>`

```
 export interface Status {
       status1: string;
       status2: string;
       status3: string;
    }   


    fetch(command, params?) {
      return this.http.post(`http://localhost:4000/${command}`, params)
        .pipe(
           map((res: any) => {
              return res.map(res =>{
                   return <Status> {
                      status1: res.stausOne,
                      status2: res.stausTwo,
                      status3: res.stausThree,  
                   }
               });                   
           }))
        .pipe(
            catchError(this.handleError)
         );
```

Comment: When I try this I get an error because `map` does not exist on type `<Observable>`.  (I am on Angular 6, btw)

Comment: do you mean that you can't  add map after post sentence??\

Comment: Correct.  `this.http.post(...).map(res...` results in the error `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.`

Comment: ok take a look to the complete example I added the method type and a return sentence

Comment: Thank you but it still doesn't like the `map` function.  I have read elsewhere that with Angular6 we need to wrap the `map` in `pipe`.  When I wrap in `pipe` it then needs `getEvents(): Observable<Object>`, but then `res.map` doesn't work because there is no `map` method on an Object.

Comment: ok. inside of your first map add the other returned map  `return res.map(event =>{ .....`